# Javascript event handled on wrong bootstrap object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently using templates to create html which contains a modal from bootstrap. I want to access each modal's show.bs.modal event. The div for each template is given by the ConEd id with a name, and within it is some code including a reference to a modal:

```
    <div id='ConEd<%=name%>'>
    ...
    <div class="modal fade" id="ConceptText" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ConceptLabel">
    ...       
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="ConceptLabel"></h4>
```

In the javascript for the page I have the following lines written for two ConEd objects which have been successfully created by name as above.

```
    var tab1 = $('#ConEd'+'input1'+' .active'); 
    var tabmodal1 = tab.find('.modal[id=ConceptText]');
    tabmodal1.on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var modal = $(this);
        modal.find('.modal-title').text('input1 title');    
    });


    var tab2 = $('#ConEd'+'input2'+' .active'); 
    var tabmodal2 = tab.find('.modal[id=ConceptText]');
    tabmodal2.on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var modal = $(this);
        modal.find('.modal-title').text('input2 title');    
    });
```

On debugging each tabmodal variable has the correct selector - is attributed to the right ConEd object.

Unfortunately whenever the modal is shown and the show.bs.modal event is fired, only the first event (with title set to 'input1 title') is fired, so both modals have title text 'input1 title'.

I cannot work out what I have done wrong to have the first even attributed to both modal objects. I would be very grateful for any pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I am reading it correctly - but the top section of your post seems to indicate that the modals are created from template - but if that top portion is a section of that template - the id is static and will therefore be given to every modal.

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="ConceptText" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ConceptLabel">
```

This means that each modal created by this template will have the id of "conceptText" and any subsequent action will therefore only apply to the first one. Therefore you may have to find a way to dynamically alter the id of each modal coming off the template.

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="<%=id%>" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ConceptLabel">
```

Comment: Thanks very much indeed. Changing the ids to be unique within the template is indeed the answer. So you can also do this: <div class="modal fade" name = "concepttext" id="<%=id%>" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ConceptLabel">, and refer to it in the event code using name - i.e. modal.find('.modal-title[name=concepttext]').text('input1 title'); - the name doesn't have to be unique as long as the ids are. The modals function by id which is why this is necessary, for an ordinary textarea you can define it without id and just name and the selector correctly grabs the correct object.

Comment: glad to be of help - it is worth remembering for all your code that each ID must be unique and if you need to have different things classed as the same to use a class or a name. If you could click the accept answer checkbox so that other users can see that the issue has been resolved. Good luck with your coding :))

Comment: apologies - should have done that sooner. Thanks again.